# Failed to update “Operating System Updates”

Tags: linux, operating-system

Running Pop!_OS 21.04 and trying to update to the latest version when I get this error.

This may have been caused by external or manually compiled software.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnode72: Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
nodejs: Conflicts: nodejs-doc
Conflicts: npm

Any quick fixes I'm able to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall nodejs and npm, try agian and install it again.

You may ask it in Pop!community. SO answer technologic problem but these.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, go it to work in the end with a fresh reinstall